Craft2 migration to new server - storage isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that
I am migrating 2 separate Craft2 websites (in IIS v7) to a new webserver.
I used Microsoft's WebDeploy utility to move the site files and their settings, and then I exported the dbs from each site, using the Craft Dashboard.
I installed the same version of PHP as was used before (7.1.5), as well as the same version of MySQL (5.7.18).
I copied the same php.ini file over from the old server, and PHP is indeed running.
The Craft web files were just copied over from the old webserver, and I checked ownership, and they both have the same ownership.
The 2 sites are identical with the exception that the first website uses Craft 2.6.2984 and the second website uses Craft 2.6.3000.
The first website runs fine, but the second one gives me this error message:
storage isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that.

The only thing that jumps out at me is that the old webserver (where the web files and db dump are from) is very slow and times-out at times, so I'm not sure if any of the files would've been corrupted during download.
Thanks for any ideas or checks that I could try in this.

You need to change the permissions of the craft/storage directory, so that PHP can write to it.
Your actual permissions might vary based on your server configuration, but I believe you can get away with something like 755.

Thanks.  Yes, I've already done this (this is in windows, so I'm unsure of the equivalent to 755).  Since the files were copied from another server, I have been suspecting some of the permissions/ownership didn't transfer over, but it looks good.  Is there a good resource on what to check, with regards to ownership, after migrating files from another server?

If you're using IIS, you need to give whatever AppPool account the site in IIS is using write permissions to that folder.
